# How do I convert the contents of a char array to their corresponding integer values in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm taking a string provided by the user and converting it to a char array by doing the following.

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
char[] charArray = userInput.ToCharArray();
```

From there I want to loop through the entire char array and convert each index to its corresponding integer value, but this is where I'm having trouble.

If my string is `"Hello World"`, My char array should look like this

`{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'}`

Then the int array would look like this

`{72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100}`

This is the loop I've written to go through the char array:

```
for (int count = 0; count<charArray.Length; count++)
        {
            myInt = charArray[count]; 
        }
```

Using this loop, I know that the value of `myInt` continues to be changed until the loop terminates. Meaning the value of `myInt` will correspond the the int value of the last index of `charArray`. I've also tried using `charArray[count] =...`, but I can't figure out how to use this properly. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this data?  `char` is actually a kind of integer, so you can do arithmetic on a `char[]` array without converting it to anything.

Comment: I'm trying to encode messages the user enters. The easiest way I could think was to turn the user string into char and then into int if that makes sense.

Comment: Having said that, you can do `int[] intArray= new int[charArray.Length];` and `Array.Copy( charArray, intArray, charArray.Length);`., but you don't need to do that.  You can just use the elements in the char array.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine())`?..

Comment: @MaciejLos No, the OP wants `'8' => 56`, not `'8' => 8`.

Comment: Encode for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You have it almost complete, but you can consider the following:

- Where will the result will be stored?

If you have an array of X number of CHARS, then you will have to make an INT array of the same length.

```
int[] intArray=new int[charArray.Length];
```

Then you can assign each element to the corresponding "box"

```
for (int count = 0; count<charArray.Length; count++)
{
    intArray[count]= (int)charArray[count]; 
}
```

You might want to cast the char to int (the parentesis with the type in it is called cast, where you can convert one type of variable to another, whenever is possible)

Comment: Calling your index variable 'count' is a bit confusing - a count is often the upper bound of a for loop.

Comment: I used almost the same code as the one the OP try, looks like he's learning and need to understand bit by bit. The less the change, the more he will know whats the logic behind the solution.

Comment: Ah of course - apologies. I should have checked.

Answer (score -1):

To get the `int` of the `char` you could do

```
myInt = (int)(charArray[count] - ‘0’);
```

Comment: This isn't what was asked.